# ASP.NET Web API Questions - Authorization / Authentication

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, wcf, model-view-controller, asp.net-web-api

I've been asked to create an API for clients. Before I begin I have some questions. I've decided to use the ASP.NET Web API technology. I've created my first method and it works fine, I'm able to return a set of results of products in XML/Json format. The problem is, anyone who accesses my API held at my website will be able to see all my products. I already have a database of customers, how can I use this so that prior to accessing my API, they have to set some credentials.

The API should be accessible to both Web and Desktop clients

One way I thought of doing it, is they pass their username/password along as parameters but this didnt seem very secure/right?. For example: `api/products/GetById/750?username=bob&pass=123`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use AuthorizeAttribute to decorate your controllers/actions.

```
[Authorize]
public IEnumerable<Product> Get() {...}
```

This can restrict your resources to be available only to authenticated users.

The actual authentication method is another story. By default Web API uses cookie-based ASP.NET forms authentication, which is good if api is directly consumed from a html+js web client.

On the other hand if your API is to be consumed by desktop/mobile apps or plugin base web client, using HTTP Basic authentication may be better as you wouldn't have to manage cookies (remember to use SSL in this scenario).

You may want to look at my blog post at http://www.piotrwalat.net/basic-http-authentication-in-asp-net-web-api-using-membership-provider/ which shows how to provide http basic authentication that uses ASP.NET membership and role providers.

Comment: This is great, but how would a client input their credentials to be authorised? Would I have to expose a method?

Comment: It depends on the client plaform you are using. For example using .NET WebClient you would probably set WebClient.Credentials property.

Answer (score 3):

Definitely not via the query string.

Why not use ASP.NET Membership? [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh26yfzy.aspx)

Alternatively, you could write your own authentication and check if the user has appropriate permissions before passing back the list of products.

http://sixgun.wordpress.com/2012/02/29/asp-net-web-api-basic-authentication/

Comment: Yeah, but how would they pass in their credentials to the Membership provider / Custom Authenticator prior to accessing my api?

Comment: @DarrenDavies no not with REST you can't, he's using Web API.

Comment: @BiffBaffBoff - Check this out: http://sixgun.co.uk/blog/2012/02/29/asp-net-web-api-basic-authentication/

Comment: Ok, that explains how to authorize, but where would a client input their credentials before calling my api?

Answer (score 3):

- You want to host your API inside a SSL folder. That will encrypt all communications (same as sending your credit card # over the web)
- You can also encrypt the URL so it will read like this:

  `api/products/GetById/750?u=828s388332e328e38&p=328e23e2i38324r423ur29834`

  But this represents a challenge since now you have to sync the encryption method used by your client
- You can also use tokens, and have your client retrieve a token with an expiration date. Tokens expire (1 hour, or 1 day, etc). Then the URL can look like this:

  `api/products/GetById/750?token=1241824123yxxcn2r348`
- You can also use private/public keys: 
  [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649260.aspx)

Comment: SSL is for encrypting the communications, but doesn't really have anything to do with authorization or authentication, which the question was about.

Comment: Although the title of the question is about Authorization and Authentication, he is worried about passing credentials from the client. SSL will help minimize the risk.

Answer (score 0):

Using a Username/Password combination is fine, but rather than passing by the query string, do it in a more standardised way (HTTP Basic Authentication) which is to add this information to the message's request header. Here is what the code would look like:

```
HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(@"https://localhost:8010/api/Customer/1");
//Add a header to the request that contains our credentials
//DO NOT HARDCODE IN PRODUCTION!! Pull credentials real-time from database or other store.
string svcCredentials = Convert.ToBase64String(ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes("user1"+ ":" + "test"));
req.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Basic " + svcCredentials);
```

You question is tagged with both 'WCF' and 'Web API' so inspecting the credentials server side is a bit different. However, you essentially pull the 'Authorization' header and inspect the credentials to see if the user is authenticated and authorized. If they are not authenticated, return back a HTTP 401 message.

For WCF REST based services hosted in IIS, you can view a full detailed example from a blog post of mine:

[Using Basic Authentication In REST Based Services Hosted in IIS](http://allen-conway-dotnet.blogspot.com/2012/07/using-basic-authentication-in-rest.html)